# MacBook Pro M1 Video Output using DVI Adaptor

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-silicon

On the MacBook Pro M1 screen the grayscale is achieved by partly turning on the pixels. I say this because under a magnifying glass there are no gaps between the pixels meaning that it is NOT a case of turning on alternate pixels.

Given that the video available from a USBC-to-DVI adaptor is digital, i.e. with no partly illuminated pixels (they are either full ON or full OFF) how will the DVI signals deliver this?

Comment: DVI is a standard protocol and doesn’t change based on the content driven by the GPU, depend on how much RAM is installed or which CPU/GPU you chose. All recent MacBook have “Thunderbolt 3 digital video output with native DisplayPort output over USB-C.  VGA, HDMI, DVI, and Thunderbolt 2 output supported using adapters (sold separately) ” What problem are you trying to solve here?

Answer (score 1):

DVI being a digital interface does not mean that pixels on the display have to be either fully on or fully off because of the digital "zeroes and ones".

Using DVI, a number of bits are transferred for each pixel to represent what we would like the display to show. The actual number of bits per pixels varies depending on your configuration - but it can be up to 48 bits in a dual-link DVI setup, but is typically 24 bits per pixels in many setups. It can also be fewer than that.

In a typical 24 bits per pixel setup, you would find that the intensity of the red, green and blue colors are described for each as a number from 0-254. I.e. 8 bit per color, 24 bits per pixel for a RGB setup.

Note that the above is a simplified explanation of how DVI works on a conceptual level. The actual signal transferred over the wire actually uses 10 bits symbols to transfer 8 bit worth of payload data.

Comment: Thanks for that. This means there can be up to 48 clock transitions for each pixel, being that the pixel definition is done serially. That increases the bandwidth of the cable and receiver substantially. Data slicing of the serial lines must be faster as is processing that data. Until I connect an oscilloscope onto the DVI output I won't know what they are doing. The reason I asked the question is that signal timing data on the DVI protocol is hard to come by.

Comment: Perhaps I should be data slicing off VGA

Comment: You should probably have mentioned in your original question that you were trying to decode things with an oscilloscope - and also what you're actually trying to do - otherwise it is hard to answer you with the right level of information.

Comment: You were right on the first time JK. Besides, is free flow of information rightly regulated according to whether someone agrees with the ultimate use? Seems a bit woke to me.

Comment: As for "clock transitions" - you should be aware that it is not a single serial bus. There's a separate serial data bus for R, G and B - and you have also have a dedicated pixel clock line. The "48" number I assume you got from the fact that it is a maximum of 48 bits of data per pixel - but when you look at a oscilloscope you'll see that each 8 bits of pixel data is encoded as 10 bits. In addition there's also control word (10 bits of size) that encode things such as vertical and horizontal sync.

Comment: You jumped to the conclusion that this had something do with "agreeing with the ultimate use" - that is a false conclusion. I don't care if you're using this information to connect a MacBook Pro to a digital sign on your roof, or you're trying to create a DVI-to-USB decoder - or whatever it is you're tinkering with. That's not why I want to know what your goal is. It is because an answer can be answered at all sorts of technical levels. A computer beginner that asks how many ones and zeroes can produce many colors on a screen deserves a different answer than an electrical engineer working [..]

Comment: with oscilloscopes and other test equipment in order to try to decode a signal for whatever purpose.

Comment: Also: When you look at the oscilloscope you should be aware that the (for example) 8-bit pixel data is converted before being put on the serial bus. It is not just 8 bits + 2 bits checksum or something like that. The 8 bits are first XOR'ed or XNOR'ed, and then finally they can all possibly be inverted before transmission. The extra 2 bits of data per pixel is used to indicate whether XOR or XNOR is used, and whether the bits are inverted or not.

Comment: If you're doing manual decoding with some test software, it is probably easiest for you to create a table of all the 2^10 combinations possible. Of those approx. half will never occur, and the other half is basically the 256 possible color levels coded in two ways (some only one way due to the nature of things) - and then the 2 types of controls for syncing.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say that the timing data is hard to come by. The original DVI specification is available to download online, and is relatively simple (when compared to for example the latest HDMI specifications).

Comment: Thanks for that JK. I agree I did jump to a conclusion in these febrile times. The resolution I need is far less in pixels and intensity than DVI offers but I shall keep your info in mind if an older standard fails at a hurdle.